# What kind of special characters can glob pattern handle?

Tags: php, glob

So far I have only worked with `*`, but, are there something like lookaheads, groups?

I would like to get all `*.php` except `controller.php`.

What I have to alter in this `glob(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.php')` call, to exclude `controller.php`?

Or should I avoid [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) and work with something else instead?

Comment: [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) combines [`scandir`](http://php.net/scandir) with [`fnmatch`](http://php.net/fnmatch). If you need more complex rules, combine [`scandir`](http://php.net/scandir) with [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) instead.  Or use the [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator) and a [`RegexIterator`](http://php.net/RegexIterator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php glob() uses the rules used by the libc glob() function, which is similar to the rules used by common shells. So the patterns that you are allowed to use are rather limited.

glob() returns an array of all the paths that match the given pattern. Filtering controller.php out the result array is one solution.

Answer (score 1):

As per http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/glob/: (the backend behind php's `glob()`) `The glob() function is a pathname generator that implements the rules for file name pattern matching used by the shell.`

It is a single filter, no exceptions. If you want *.php, you'll get *.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
$availableFiles = glob("*.txt");
foreach ($availableFiles as $key => $filename) {
    if($filename == "controller.php"){
        unset($availableFiles[$key]);
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($availableFiles);
?>
```